# Symfony - Check if controller exists

Tags: php, symfony

My situation: I have a NavigatorController which is triggered by AJAX requests, and will

> $this->forward("controllername")

the request. But how can I check if the controller exists based on controller name? Of course, BEFORE the actual forward happens and throws an error when the page controller does not exists.

Comment: you can check if the class exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually use the 
*controller_resolver*
service that Symfony uses in order to check if controller exists.

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $request->attributes->set('_controller', 'AppBundle\Controller\ExampleController::exampleAction');
    try{
        $this->get('debug.controller_resolver')->getController($request);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $x = $e->getCode();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But does it return the called controller's Response now?

Comment: No it does not call the controller. Just instantiate it and return the object.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Also You can check by using `Service`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

class ExampleService
{
    /**
     * @param string $controller
     * @return bool
     */
    public function has($controller)
    {
        list($class, $action) = explode('::', $controller, 2);
        return class_exists($class);
    }
}
```

In `app/config/services.yml` :

```
services:
    app.controller.check:
        class: AppBundle\Service\ExampleService
```

In `Controller`:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $controller = 'AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController';
    if($this->get('app.controller.check')->has($controller))
    {
        echo 'Exists';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Doesn't exists";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great workaround, thank you for sharing! :)